# difference results between "npm run in termimal" vs VSCode npm script explorer while deploying to firebase

Tags: firebase, visual-studio-code, npm, zsh, firebase-tools

I have a firebase deploy script in my package.json: `deploy:firestore:triggers:ProcessUpdate`

When I run this from the 'npm script explorer window' in vscode I get the error:

> Error: Cannot deploy function with runtime nodejs18

When I run `npm run deploy:firestore:triggers:ProcessUpdate` in the zsh terminal it succeeds.

I have these settings in settings.json:

```
  "terminal.integrated.shellIntegration.enabled": true,
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "zsh",
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": "zsh",
```

Why could running from the vscode npm script explorer fail?

Comment: Shouldn't you tag it _vscode_ and post it on  i.e. [su] instead of StackOverflow? This looks to me at just a mere configuration problem for Vscode.